# Can't pass data to Vue component

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 components `ProfileComponent` and `UserSettingsComponent`. I connect the navigation bar to both of these components `<NavbarComponent :user="user"></NavbarComponent>`, and accordingly, in `NavbarComponent` I pass the user I took from the components `ProfileComponent` and `UserSettingsComponent`

In the `NavbarComponent` itself I have a regular link `<router-link>`, which takes a slug as a parameter

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user.page', params: { slug: user.slug }}">Home</router-link>
```

The problem is that when I am in the `ProfileComponent` everything works, but when I am in the user `UserSettingsComponent` I get an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "slug"
```

I commented out the link and tried to just output the slug, and it did. But as soon as I uncommented the link in `UserSettingsComponent`, I again received an error that the slug was missing

```
<ul class="nav me-auto">
<li class="nav-item">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'user.page', params: { slug: user.slug }}">Home</router-link> Doesn't WORK
</li>
{{user.slug}} It WORK!!!
</ul>
```

Comment: you are getting user data asynchronies so you should use v-if on router-link. or also you can use v-if on the root tag of your component to be executed when user info exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `user` is asynchronously fetched data. Until the data is fetched, `user.slug` is undefined.  The component tries to load anyways, and when it tries to render a link with undefined `user.slug` it causes an error.

`{{ user.slug }}` would also cause an error but the [text interpolation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation)  reactively updates as soon as the `user` information is received. The reactive update happens too fast for you to notice anything wrong.

One quick solution is to just add a `v-if` which will only render the router-link once `user.slug` is defined.

```html
<router-link
  v-if="user.slug"
  :to="{ name: 'Home', params: { slug: user.slug } }"
>
  Home
</router-link>
```

You haven't revealed anything about how `user` is defined or updated so you might need `v-if="user"` if the entire object is initially null or undefined.